# MySQL auto-increment restarted unwanted

Tags: mysql

I have a table with some data with an id field which is AI (auto increment), it gets inserted each day thousands of rows.

In order, this table should not get extremely big I archived the data after using it, with these statements:

```
INSERT INTO archive_table (SELECT * FROM table WHERE date = <my dates>);
DELETE FROM table WHERE WHERE date = <my dates>;
```

The problem I have is that the first table gets restarted the auto-increment again from 1.

Can anyone advice how it's happening? I want to continue the auto-increment

Comment: Does that column actually have auto_increment specified? Can you post `SHOW CREATE TABLE <your table>`?

Comment: How exactly are you "**archiving the data after using it**"? Are you removing the rows every day?

Comment: Ensure that you don't have any triggers attached.

Comment: @TheImpaler
INSERT INTO archive_table (SELECT * FROM table WHERE date = <my dates>);
DELETE FROM table WHERE WHERE date = <my dates>;

Comment: Just a thought, For a finer control of an auto increment column you could use sequences. Unfortunately, those are available on MariaDB 10.3 only, not on MySQL.

Comment: @SalmanA
'CREATE TABLE <my_table> (`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, .....<all the tables>..... PRIMARY KEY (`id`), UNIQUE KEY `new_id_UNIQUE` (`id`)) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=43454 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8'

Comment: @Leib this is weird, deleting from table should not reset the auto increment unless you delete _all_ rows using `TRUNCATE TABLE` command.

Comment: @SalmanA Yes that what I know, I tried to create a new table and start using that, hope will not have the issue anymore.
Anyway thanks for trying to help me.

Comment: Oh, again with the same issue, every time my table get empty the AUTO_INCREMENT starts again. I DID NOT USE TRUNCATE, JUST DELETE THE ROWS